# HTML video doesn't fit after API call - next.js and styled-components

Tags: html, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

I have this Facebook clone, and user should be able to post videos, post publications, like and all that stuff.

The problem in my app is that, every time I make an action, like liking a pub or creating a comment, it makes an API call to the server, and because I'm using SWR hook along with Next.js, before the API call I have to mutate my cache (data) and that makes the data re-render so to speak, and the videos in the app disappear momentaneously. That causes that the container's height to fit the video before was for example `25vh`, when video disappears the container becomes `22vh`, those `3vh` provide a bad experience, since, if I'm liking a post, the user will feel like the screen has moved for no reason so to speak.

What can I do so my HTML tag video, even though it might not be there, I want it to have the height it should took to fit container (since I don't want all videos to have same height, some of them might be big, some of them small).

Let me show you some code.

When i like pub

```js
const LikePub = async (): Promise<void> => {}
```

Here's the video

```js
{/* Image */}
{publication.photo && (
    <PubImage>
        {publication.photo.split("")[5] === "v" ? (
            <video
              // src={publication.photo}
              controls={onVideo}
              onMouseOver={() => setOnVideo(true)}
              onMouseOut={() => setOnVideo(false)}
            >
              <source src={publication.photo} />
            </video>
        ) : (
            <img src={publication.photo} alt="" />
        )}
    </PubImage>
)}
```

These are the styles

```js
// PubImage

export const PubImage = styles.div`
    width: 100%;
    img, video {
        width: 100%;
        min-height: 28vh;
        max-height: 80vh;
        object-fit: cover;
        display: block;
    }
`;
```

What can I do? Do I have to set same height for all videos (I don't want that)?

Comment: What if you put the video inside the container, set the container rigid width and height, and vertically center your video inside the container?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but i already figured out a solution !

Comment: @Diego You may want to add your solution as an answer to your own question, to help users who might face a similar issue in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the answer i wanted, if you maybe are facing a similar issue, just set directly the property height, so the video and container will have the same measures